# WPF Storyboard animation with MultiDataTrigger multiple condition for background image ViewBox exception

Tags: c#, wpf, multidatatrigger

In my project I have a single file to create most of the styles for WPF. I am trying to set a background of a TextBlock and animate its ViewBox to give it a carousel effect. I have been able to do is successfully when all the controls exists when the application loads. However right after I add a control matching the new triggers it throws an exception. Here is my code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <!-- Image Carousal -->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}, AncestorLevel=4},Path=Name}" Value="WelcomeScreen_Master" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=Name}" Value="LayoutMainTitleGrid" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Name}" Value="Banner"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="146" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="620,200,0,0" />
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush
                                            ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/LoremTheme;component/images/rotate.png" 
                                            Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                            AlignmentY="Top" 
                                            AlignmentX="Right"
                                            ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,400,146"
                                            ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,300,109.5"
                                            >
                                    </ImageBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <RectAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Viewbox"
                                        To="0,0,400,146" BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

The code works if i set the background image of the TextBlock in code but its not an options as the application will have different style files. If I remove the  from the above style I can still set the border without animation, which means the xaml is able to set the background. But if I maintain  it gives the following exception.

```
---------------------------
Active Window : Exception
---------------------------


 Method:Void VerifyPathIsAnimatable(System.Windows.PropertyPath)

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Background.Viewbox'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.VerifyPathIsAnimatable(PropertyPath path)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock currentClock, DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope, DependencyObject parentObject, String parentObjectName, PropertyPath parentPropertyPath, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, HybridDictionary clockMappings, Int64 layer)
```

How can I make the animation work ? Right now my assumption is the animation is starting before the style sets the background, so is there a way to delay the storyboard ? or is there another solution ?